# Read more no longer displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

After upgrading WordPress, TinyMCE Excerpt stopped working, and so did the excerpt code within thehypebr.com/index.php. I'm not sure why Read More doesn't display after each excerpt.

```
        <div class="custom_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt('Read more &raquo;'); ?></div><div class="separator">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: this is hardly enough Information to go on, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_excerpt()` doesn't take any parameters. Only `the_content()` takes that parameter. You're going to have to add a read more link another way if you want to use the excerpt.

### EDIT

To add a permalink after the excerpt, you could do this:

```
the_excerpt();
echo '<p><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read More...</a></p>';
```

Comment: Thanks - any suggestions on how I can add the Read More link in another way?

Comment: You could do so either programmatically with a filter, or by adding a hardcoded permalink afterward that says 'Read More'

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. Where and how can I hardcode a permalink?

Comment: I added a snippet to my answer that will do that. :)